# Created a string in Java, S = "httthhhtth". Split it in a half and change second half 'H' into 'T' and 'T' into 'H'

Tags: java, arrays, string

I managed to split the string but how can I swap h with t and t with h in second half of string ?

```
public class Tollring3 {

   public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
      
       String base = "httthhhtth";
      int half = base.length()/2;
       // int half = base.length() % 2 == 0 ? base.length()/2 : base.length()/2 + 1;
       String first = base.substring(0, half);
       String second = base.substring(half);
       System.out.println("Actual String :- "+base);
       System.out.println(first);
       System.out.println(second);
       char[] c = second.toCharArray();

    // Replace with a "swap" function, if desired:
    char temp = c[0];
    c[0] = c[1];
    c[1] = temp;

    String swappedString = new String(c);
    System.out.println(swappedString);
    } 
}
```

How to swap h with t and t with h in second half of string

Comment: You could use a for loop to iterate through the second half of the string, and if the character is 'h', change it to 't', and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

This program splits a string into two halves, then swaps the first and second characters of the second half.
public class Tollring3 {

```
   public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
      
       String base = "httthhhtth";
      int half = base.length()/2;
       // int half = base.length() % 2 == 0 ? base.length()/2 : base.length()/2 + 1;
       String first = base.substring(0, half);
       String second = base.substring(half);
       System.out.println("Actual String :- "+base);
       System.out.println(first);
       System.out.println(second);
       char[] c = second.toCharArray();

    // Replace with a "swap" function, if desired:
    char temp = c[0];
    c[0] = c[1];
    c[1] = temp;

    String swappedString = new String(c);
    System.out.println(swappedString);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I don't get what you did, seems nothing changed, so ?

Answer (score 0):

To do the replacement you need to iterate on the chars and use `if` to test what char it is

```
String base = "httthhhtth";
System.out.println(base);

char[] c = base.toCharArray();
for (int i = c.length / 2; i < c.length; ++i) {
    if (c[i] == 'h') {
        c[i] = 't';
    } else if (c[i] == 't') {
        c[i] = 'h';
    }
}

String swappedString = new String(c);
System.out.println(swappedString);
```

```
httthhhtth
httthtthht
```

Comment: Why not `for (int i = c.length / 2; i < c.length; ++i)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `swap` function as follows:

```
String swap(String str) {
    char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
    char[] result = new char[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        result[i] = arr[i] == 'h' ? 't' : arr[i] == 't' ? 'h' : arr[i];

    return new String(result);
}
```

In the function, we have

1. split the given string (second half) into a `char` array, `arr`.
2. created another `char` array, `result` of the same size.
3. iterates `arr` to store each character from `arr` into `result` while swapping `h` and `t` with each other.
4. finally returned a new `String` created out of `result`.

**Full demo**:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String base = "httthhhtth";
        int half = base.length() / 2;
        // int half = base.length() % 2 == 0 ? base.length()/2 : base.length()/2 + 1;
        String first = base.substring(0, half);
        String second = base.substring(half);
        System.out.println("Actual String :- " + base);
        System.out.println(first);
        System.out.println(second);

        String swappedString = swap(second);
        System.out.println(swappedString);
    }

    static String swap(String str) {
        char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
        char[] result = new char[arr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            result[i] = arr[i] == 'h' ? 't' : arr[i] == 't' ? 'h' : arr[i];

        return new String(result);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Actual String :- httthhhtth
httth
hhtth
tthht
```